# Mac: How to log in as different user when Mac requires password to wake from sleep?

Tags: macos, mac, login, sleep, screensaver

If your Mac is set up to **require a password** when being awoke from **sleep** or the **screen saver** is it **possible to log in as a different user?** If so how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you enable "Show fast user switching menu" in System Preferences → Accounts, then the lock screen gains a new button "Switch User..." which will take you to the login screen.

On Mac OS X Snow Leopard and previous, the Switch User button appears on the password dialog:

[image: Mac OS X Snow Leopard Switch User button]

On Mac OS X Lion, the button appears at the bottom of the screen:

[image: Mac OS X Lion Switch User button]

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought but had to look a bit harder for it in Lion. It's no longer in the dialog as you've shown. It's now at the bottom of the lock screen.

Comment: Ah, so you're right. I don't have Lion so I didn't know they moved it. I added that detail to my answer, thanks!

Comment: FYI- there is a [related bug in Mountain Lion](http://superuser.com/questions/465441/switch-user-from-locked-screensaver) if there is only one *Local* user account and a *Network* user wants to log in from the lock screen.